# Missing core folder in Xamarin Forms project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I created a new Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2022 an called it "App1".
After initializing the project, I see the App1.Android and App1.iOS, but the App1 folder is missing.
When I open the project in the explorer (rightclick on project -> open in explorer) the App1 folder exists.

I can't compile the project, ass VS is saying the reference to App1 does not exist.
Anyone can help me? Thanks :D

Reinstalled VS, nothing changed.

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got it running... ^^
I went to C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet and deleted everything within.